# .NET 6 core application won't run from specified URL

Tags: .net, deployment, publish

I have a .NET 6 Core Razor application that connects to a database. I have created a publish profile for it in Visual Studio 2022, and have given it a URL of localhost:8080.
It published successfully, but when I try to run it at the above URL, I receive an error message:
HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

I looked at other questions on StackOverflow.com about this, and one person said to try running it from the command line in the directory where the application resides like this:
dotnet .dll

When I try that, it tells me that is it listening on http://localhost:5000 or https://localhost:5001. When I try running it on those ports from the browser, it works just fine.

Anyone have any ideas why it won't work on the URL I gave it in the publish profile, but it will work from another port if I run it from the command line?